# MySQL conditional check in a non procedure statement

Tags: mysql

I would like to check if a MySQL db exists, and if it does grant permission to a user.

```
SELECT Count(schema_name) 
FROM   information_schema.schemata 
WHERE  schema_name = 'tmx' 
INTO   @found ;SELECT @found; -- Verified, the result is 1IF (@FOUND == 1) THEN 
  GRANT 
  SELECT, 
  UPDATE 
  ON tmx.* TO 'my_new_user'@'%';END IF;
```

When i execute the code above I my sql error out on the IF-statement.
Is it possible to run the IF-statement outside stored procedure?
The reason I prefer to not use stored procedure is because I would like to get the shortest syntax possible. What would be the shortest commands to achieve this?

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF (@FOUND == 1) THEN  GRANT SELECT, UPDATE ON tmx.* TO 'my_new_user'@'%'' at line 1

I'm currently on mysqld  Ver 5.7.31 for Linux on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server (GPL))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, MySQL only supports compounds statements in stored routines.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-compound-statements.html

> This section describes the syntax for the BEGIN ... END compound statement and other statements that can be used in the body of stored programs: Stored procedures and functions, triggers, and events

"Other statements" in this context include flow-control statements like `IF / THEN / ELSE / ENDIF`.

Most developers who need to do conditional code will write the conditions in some client programming language such as Java or Python. Nearly any other language you like will have a connector for MySQL too.

Comment: Surprisingly MySQL didn't complain if the db doesn't exists, so maybe the if is not that important for my purpose since that non existing db will be created eventually `GRANT SELECT, UPDATE ON some_new_db_doent_exist_yet.* TO 'my_new_user'@'%';`